# No improvement in Validation accuracy(LeNet-5) even with Dropout,L2 and more data

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to train LeNet 5 with 16 outputs on gray scale images of size (30x30x1). I tried with 12,800 samples with no dropout and regularizer using Adam optimizer in Keras and able to achieve 100% training accuracy after 400 epochs with batch size 100, whereas Validation accuracy achieved a maximum of 65% with [no dropout and regularizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfLhv.png).

I tried with increasing data, adding L2 regularizer and Dropout but not a big improvement in validation accuracy as shown, whereas divergence.

- [12,800 samples, Dropout = 0.1(in Dense layers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHIMh.png),
- [12,800 samples, Dropout = 0.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAmw7.png),
- [Loss for 12,800 samples, Dropout = 0.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yuivw.png),
- [Loss -12,800 samples no Dropout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF0OY.png),
- [Double the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBhta.png).

Could you suggest how should I proceed with fixing this problem of over-fitting (afaik)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things:

- Increase your dropout rate, say to 0.5
- Stop training your model earlier, to prevent overfitting. This can be done with the EarlyStopping callback.
- Augment your training data to introduce noise. In theory, this can help your model learn the features that are relevant to your problem and not noise.
- Consider how similar your validation data are to your training data. Should you expect the model to perform similarly on your validation data?

Comment: Hi Jaku,Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I tried out your suggestions but after introducing early stopping and increasing dropout rate both the training and validation accuracy settles at a very lower value. I have augmented my data with noise to the fullest (if I add more it doesn't serve my purpose). Yeah, I expect my model to perform similarly on validation data and I require around 90% accuracy. One concern : My entire data can be broadly classified into two classes (that NN turned out to be great) but when I'm trying to identify the underlying classification (16 classes) problem arises.

Comment: Also would you suggest me to try with an even simpler Neural Network?

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the excellent pointers given by jakub.

1. It's almost always essential to shuffle your train and validation data before feeding it to your model, so that both sets contain similar distribution of images.
2. Let's assume you have segregated the data into two sets and have put them into the following paths:

> train_dir = '/data/training'
>
> validation_dir = '/data/validation'

The first thing to do at this point is to divide each pixel by 255, so that they are re-scaled between 0 and 1. On top of that it generally pays off to augment the data by various transformations, e.g. shear, rotation, zoom, flip etc because it generalizes the model to some extent. Both of these can be achieved using the `ImageDataGenerator` module as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Add our data-augmentation parameters to ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.,
                                   rotation_range = 40,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   height_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

# Note that the validation data should not be augmented!
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )

# Flow training images in batches of 100 using train_datagen generator
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                    batch_size = 100,
                                                    class_mode = 'binary', 
                                                    target_size = (30, 30))     

# Flow validation images in batches of 100 using test_datagen generator
validation_generator =  test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                                          batch_size  = 100,
                                                          class_mode  = 'binary', 
                                                          target_size = (30, 30))
```

3. Now, usually 100% accuracy on training data means either the features are pretty simple or the model is over-fitting. It might be useful to create a callback to set a threshold for training accuracy. In simple terms, training would stop if the training accuracy hits the threshold. We can set it to 99%, just as an example.

All this is fine, but unfortunately it won't look at the accuracy of validation set. To fix that, we can introduce a regularizer known as *early stopping*  that'll help us stop training as soon as the validation accuracy stops improving. If you look at the graphs you shared, validation accuracy peaks at about 25 epochs. After that you're most probably just over-fitting. A primer on keras early stopping is available [here](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/). So, let's instantialize both the callbacks, and use them in the training phase.

```
# Define a Callback class that stops training once accuracy reaches 98%
class MyCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    if(logs.get('acc')>0.99):
      print("\nReached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!")
      self.model.stop_training = True

training_clbk = MyCallback()

# Define the early stopping Callback
early_stopper_clbk = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_loss",
    min_delta=0,
    patience=0,
    verbose=0,
    mode="auto",
    baseline=None,
    restore_best_weights=False,
)

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      epochs=100,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      callbacks = [training_clbk, early_stopper_clbk],
      verbose=2)
```

This should take care of some of the *probable* overfitting problems you're facing. Of-course dropbout, and regularization helps in most cases, so please play around with that as well.